Recovering Veracrypt volume on encrypted hdd disk recovery after formating
An encrypted Veracrypt volume on external hdd that is 1-pass wiped (full format) with the Windows format tool. Then some data was written after the format. According to my knowledge, with hex viewer the Veracrypt volume appears full of random data, except the header which I tried to recover using Veracrypt but failed. So for me to mount the volume and retrieve the data, the full past state of the drive must be recovered as a whole.
Is recovery possible in any way?

The data is gone. I hope you realize that. If you wanted the data why did you format the HDD?

I was just reorganizing file picking the most important then after a period of time I realized that there was more files.
